# How to make will_paginate start from # and not from 1 page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, infinite-scroll, will-paginate

I'm looking for a solution to make my will_paginate start from # and not from 1 page cause when I start from 1 page I have a bug in my infinity scroll.

Someone can help me?

my infinite scroll looks like =>

```
 $(document).on('ready Turbolinks:load', function () {
        var isLoading = false;
        if ($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
            $(window).on('scroll', function() {
       more_acti_url = $('#actti .next a[rel="next"]').attr('href');
                 }

if(!isLoading && more_acti_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
                    isLoading = true;
                    $.getScript(more_acti_url).done(function
                        (data,textStatus,jqxhr) {
                        isLoading = false;
                        alert("a");
                    }).fail(function() {
                        isLoading = false;
                        alert("a2");
                    });
                }});
               }});
```

my html pagination looks like =>

```
<div style="" id="infinite-scrolling">
  <div class="pagination" id="actti">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="prev previous_page disabled">
        <a href="#">&#8592; Previous</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="/type_activites/Tous?activo_page=1">1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item">
        <a rel="next" href="/type_activites/Tous?activo_page=2">2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item">
        <a href="/type_activites/Tous?activo_page=3">3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="next next_page ">
        <a rel="next" href="/type_activites/Tous?activo_page=2">Next &#8594;</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I refesh my page and I scroll pagination go to number 3 directly . What I would like is my pagination start at 1 page and when I scroll go to number 2 and not 3 ( Sorry for my english I'm french)

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: `.paginate(page:params[:page] + #)` should do it. # being the number from which you want to paginate.